# flatten python tuple - django field options optgroups

Tags: python, django, flatten, optgroup

I've been looking for a way to flatten a field's options in django that is structured as optgroup nested tuples:

```
CHOICES = (
  ('', (
        ('value1', 'label1'),
        ('value2', 'label2'),
      )
  ),
  ('Group2', (
        ('value3', 'label3'),
        ('value4', 'label4'),
     )
  ),
)
```

What I want to achieve is a list containing only the values `['value1', 'value2', 
 'value3', 'value4']`.

I have tried itertools chain, zip and sum but I cannot get rid of the grouping labels, that is the empty string '' and 'Group2'. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the following will do:

```
[tuple[0] for tuple in [field].get_flatchoices(False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in order to do that:

```
[choice[0] for group in CHOICES for choice in group[1]]
```

Comment: I tried that, but the length of the tuples and groups is arbitrary. Thank you for your answer, nonetheless.